# Cythonize list of all splits of a string

Tags: python, cython

I'm trying to speed up a piece of code that generates all possible splits of a string.

```
splits('foo') -> [('f', 'oo'), ('fo', 'o'), ('foo', '')]
```

The code for this in python is very simple:

```
def splits(text):
    return [(text[:i + 1], text[i + 1:])
            for i in range(len(text))]
```

Is there a way to speed this up via cython or some other means? For context, the greater purpose of this code is to find the split of a string with the highest probability.

Comment: Have you done anything with Cython before?  With strings in Cython?  Py2 v Py3 (bytestrings v. unicode)?

Comment: Nope. Was trying to get started but finding strings + cython daunting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This isn't the sort of problem that Cython tends to help with much. It's using slicing, which ends up largely the same speed as pure Python (i.e. actually pretty good).

Using a 100 character long byte string (`b'0'*100`) and 10000 iterations in `timeit` I get:

- Your code as written - 0.37s
- Your code as written but compiled in Cython - 0.21s
- Your code with the line `cdef int i` and compiled in Cython - 0.20s (this is reproducably a small improvement. It's more significant with longer strings)
- Your `cdef int i` and the parameter typed to `bytes text` - 0.28s (i.e. worse).
- Best speed is got by using the Python C API directly (see code below) - 0.11s. I've chosen to do this mostly in Cython (but calling the API functions myself) for convenience, but you could write very similar code in C directly with a little more manual error checking. I've written this for the Python 3 API assuming you're using bytes objects (i.e. `PyBytes` instead of `PyString`) so if you're using Python 2, or Unicode and Python 3 you'll have to change it a little.

  ```
  from cpython cimport *
  cdef extern from "Python.h":
      # This isn't included in the cpython definitions
      # using PyObject* rather than object lets us control refcounting
      PyObject* Py_BuildValue(const char*,...) except NULL

  def split(text):
     cdef Py_ssize_t l,i
     cdef char* s

     # Cython automatically checks the return value and raises an error if 
     # these fail. This provides a type-check on text
     PyBytes_AsStringAndSize(text,&s,&l)
     output = PyList_New(l)

     for i in range(l):
         # PyList_SET_ITEM steals a reference
         # the casting is necessary to ensure that Cython doesn't
         # decref the result of Py_BuildValue
         PyList_SET_ITEM(output,i,
                         <object>Py_BuildValue('y#y#',s,i+1,s+i+1,l-(i+1)))
     return output
  ```
- If you don't want to go all the way with using the C API then a version that preallocates the list `output = [None]*len(text)` and does a for-loop rather than a list comprehension is marginally more efficient than your original version - 0.18s

In summary, just compiling it in Cython gives you a decent speed up (a bit less than 2x) and setting the type of `i` helps a little. This is all you can really achieve with Cython conventionally. To get full speed you basically need to resort to using the Python C API directly. That gets you a little under a 4x speed up which I think is pretty decent.

Comment: Wow. If I'm using unicode in python 2, what would I change this to? Is it just a matter of replacing `PyBytes_AsStringAndSize` with something else?

Comment: Unicode is more complicated. I can't see a direct replacement for `AsStringAndSize`. I think part of the problem is that there's multiple options for the data type it's stored in (decided at compile time in Python2 and runtime in Python3). I think you need two calls to `PyUnicode_GET_SIZE` and `PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE`. You'll also need to check the type first since these functions don't do it. Finally you need to change 'y#' to 'u#' in `Py_BuildValue`. Python3 is more complex because of the runtime variable character size.

Comment: Seems like I also had to replace `cdef char*` with `cdef Py_UNICODE*` for it to compile, but now it works. Awesome!