# how to define a list in Cython

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, cython

I want to transform the below `python` code in `Cython`:

```
x_array = []

x_array.append(x_new)
```

I tried the following Cython codes but it gives error:

```
cdef np.ndarray[double, dim=1] x_array

x_array.append(x_new)
```

The error shows:

`Cannot coerce list to type [double, dim=1]`

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. Please have a read on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You've typed is as a numpy array rather than a list. There isn't really an advantage to trying to fixing the type of builtin Python objects such as `list`

Comment: is there a way to fix the problem? i have a lot of list objects in my python code. Is there a way of using Cython to improve the performance?

Answer (score 19):

Your options are:

1. `cdef list x_array`. This lets Cython know that the type of `x_array` is actually a list. You may get a small speed-up from this.
2. Make `x_array` a numpy array instead. If all the elements in the list are the same simple, numeric type then this is probably a better option. Be aware that `append`ing to numpy arrays is likely to be pretty slow, so you should calculate the size in advance.

   ```
   cdef np.array[double, dim=1] x_array = np.zeros((some_precomputed_size,))
   # or
   cdef double[:] x_array = np.zeros((some_precomputed_size,))
   ```

   Note that this will only give you a speed-up for some types of operations (mostly accessing individual elements in Cython)
3. If you're set on using Python `list`s you can sometimes get a speed-up by accessing them through the Python C API in Cython. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43553763/cythonize-list-of-all-splits-of-a-string/43557675#43557675) provides an example of where that worked well. This works best when you know a size in advance and so you can pre-allocate the array (i.e. don't `append`!) and also avoid some Cython reference counting. It's very easy to go wrong and make reference counting errors with this method, so proceed carefully.