# Optimize cython functions operating on python lists

Tags: python, scipy, cython

I am currently migrating to Cython a set of functions that are currently implemented in C++ through scipy.weave (now deprecated).
These functions operate on timeseries points that are 2D-lists (eg. [[17100, 19.2], [17101, 20.7], [17102, 20.3], ...]) both in input and in output. A sample function is `subtract` that accepts two timeseries and calculates a new timeserie as subtraction of the two inputs going date-by-date.

The structure and the interfaces have to be mantained for retrocompatibility, but my profiling trials show that Cython porting is about 30%-40% slower than the original scipy.weave implementation.
I have tried many ways to optimize (inner conversions to Numpy arrays and memoryviews, C pointers, ...), but the conversion time required lenghtens the overall execution time. Even trying to define input and output as C++ vectors, leveraging on Cython implicit conversions doesn't seem to be effective in order to mantain scipy.weave speed. I have also used the various hints on boundscheck, wraparound, division, ...

The highest slow-downs seem to be on functions that uses nested loops and I've seen that a little gain can be predefining the list size (`cdef list target = [[-1, float('nan')]]*size`).

I am aware that Cython can't be so much performing on Python structures, especially lists, but are there any other tricks or techniques with which a speedup can be obtained?

=== EDIT - ADD CODE EXAMPLE ===
A good example of the typology of functions is the following.
The function takes a 2-D list of dates/prices and a 2-D list of dates/decimal factors and searches matching dates between the two lists, calculating the output on the corresponding price/factor by multiplying or dividing (that is a third input parameter).

My best-performing cython code:

```
@cython.cdivision(True)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cpdef apply_conversion(list original_timeserie, list factor_timeserie, int divide_or_multiply=False):
    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t i, j = 0, size = len(original_timeserie), size2 = len(factor_timeserie)
        long original_date, factor_date
        double original_price, factor_price, conv_price
        list result = []

    for i in range(size):
        original_date = original_timeserie[i][0]

        for j in range(j, size2):
            factor_date = factor_timeserie[j][0]

            if original_date == factor_date:
                original_price = original_timeserie[i][1]
                factor_price = factor_timeserie[j][1]

                if divide_or_multiply:
                    if factor_price != 0:
                        conv_price = original_price / factor_price
                    else:
                        conv_price = float('inf')
                else:
                    conv_price = original_price * factor_price

                result.append([original_date, conv_price])
                break

    return result
```

The original scipy function:

```
int len = original_timeserie.length();
int len2 = factor_timeserie.length();

PyObject* py_serieconv = PyList_New(len);
PyObject* original_item = NULL;
PyObject* factor_item = NULL;
PyObject* date = NULL;
PyObject* value = NULL;
long original_date = 0;
long factor_date = 0;
double original_price = 0;
double factor_price = 0;

int j = 0;

for(int i=0;i<len;i++) {
    original_item = PyList_GetItem(original_timeserie, i);
    date = PyList_GetItem(original_item, 0);
    original_date  = PyInt_AsLong(date);
    original_price = PyFloat_AsDouble( PyList_GetItem(original_item, 1) );

    factor_item = NULL;
    for(;j<len2;) {
        factor_item  = PyList_GetItem(factor_timeserie, j++);
        factor_date = PyInt_AsLong(PyList_GetItem(factor_item, 0));
        if (factor_date == original_date) {
            factor_price = PyFloat_AsDouble(PyList_GetItem(factor_item, 1));
            value = PyFloat_FromDouble(original_price * (divide_or_multiply==0 ? factor_price : 1/factor_price));
            PyObject* py_new_item = PyList_New(2);
            Py_XINCREF(date);
            PyList_SetItem(py_new_item, 0, date);
            PyList_SetItem(py_new_item, 1, value);
            PyList_SetItem(py_serieconv, i, py_new_item);                        
            break;
        }
    } 
}

return_val = py_serieconv;
Py_XDECREF(py_serieconv);
```

Comment: You [can sometimes get decent speedups using the C-API within Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43553763/cythonize-list-of-all-splits-of-a-string/43557675#43557675) to preallocate lists more efficiently. For anything more useful than that you'd need to produce an [mcve]

Comment: I expanded the question with a full example

Comment: It looks like the scipy version is doing most of the things I'd recommend. I doubt if it can be improved too much.