# Cython - Declare List from Input

Tags: python, c, cython, cythonize

I am trying to convert a list of objects (GeoJSON) to shapely objects using cython, but I am running into a error:

This piece of code seems to be the issue: `cdef object result[N]`.  How do I declare a list/array from a given `list`?

Here is my current code:

```py
def  convert_geoms(list array):
    cdef int i, N=len(array)
    cdef double x, s=0.0
    cdef object result[N]  # ERROR HERE
    for i in range(N):
        g = build_geometry_objects2(array[i])
        result[i] = g
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two issues with `cdef object result[N]`:

1. It creates a C array of Python objects - this doesn't really work because C arrays aren't easily integrated with the Python object reference counting (in this you'd need to copy the whole array to something else when you returned it anyway, since it's a local variable that's only scoped to the function).
2. For C arrays of the form `sometype result[N]`, `N` must be known at compile-time. In this case `N` is different for each function call, so the variable definition is invalid anyway.

---

There's multiple solutions - most of them involve just accepting that you're using Python objects so not worrying about specifying the types and just writing valid Python code. I'd probably write it as a list comprehension. I suspect Cython will do surprisingly well at producing optimized code for that

```
return [ build_geometry_objects2(array[i]) for i in range(len(array)) ]
# or
return [ build_geometry_objects2(a) for a in array ]
```

The second version is probably better, but if it matters you can time it.

If the performance really matters you can use Python C API calls which you can `cimport` from `cpython.list`. See [Cythonize list of all splits of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43553763/cythonize-list-of-all-splits-of-a-string/43557675#43557675) for an example of something similar where list creation is optimized this way. The advantage of `PyList_New` is that it creates an appropriately sized list at the start filled with `NULL` pointers, which you can then fill in.